# C: realloc updates address of struct, but not addresses of pointers within struct

Tags: c, pointers, realloc

I have a pointer to a trie of structs that gradually increases in size, so I realloc when needed. After a certain point, realloc returns a new address, and moves the structs. The issue though, is that within the structs are more pointers, which point to the address of another struct within the block. When the block gets shifted to a new address, the pointers addresses stay the same, so now all point to invalid locations within the original block.

Is there a good way to mitigate this issue? All I can think of is instead of storing pointers in the struct, is to store an offset value to direct a pointer to the next struct. This is do-able, but I imagine there must be some form of normal operation people do in this case, as this situation surely isnt that uncommon?

Otherwise, having a pointer within an allocated block that points to another address within that block is pretty useless if used with realloc

Comment: Can I ask why you're increasing the size of your structure? It sounds to me that you may wish to create a linked list of structures - each structure containing a pointer to the next structure (and possibly the previous one), allocating memory for the new structure and updating the structure pointers accordingly.

Comment: @ChrisBD Yes sorry, that is what Im doing. The struct stays the same size, the number of structs in the list increases, and so realloc is needed to allow for an additional struct to be placed into the block. Its actually a trie (as far as my understanding goes), but the same idea. I edited the OP to match this

Comment: If you have a linked list, the last list entry has a member for pointing to a new element in your list. There is no reason (only if you did not tell us so), why you should move your existing structures into one memory block! That's the charm with a linked list. You can extend the linked list, by creating a new object and make the last list entry point to that new object. The existing objects in the list do NOT have to be reallocated!

Comment: *Is there a good way to mitigate this issue?* Yes. Don't mix embedded pointers and `realloc()`. It's a fundamentally bad design. You have to go through your **entire** list looking for references to the old location of the block after calling `realloc()` when the location changes. *having a pointer within an allocated block that points to another address within that block is pretty useless if used with realloc* Exactly. There's no point in doing something "useless".  It's better to not blow your own foot off with a foot gun than it is to have to put the pieces of your foot back each time.

Comment: @Mr.Yellow Im doing it this way so that all the structs in the list are stored in the same allocated block, so I can then free all data used by simply freeing just the 1 block. Rather than running through the list, freeing 1 by 1, as the end result would have roughly 150k members, and this is a timed process. Also this is more of a trie, so I dont really have a good way of going through all the paths of the members to free them. Is this reasonable thinking, or would you say this is not the best approach?

Comment: So you save some time (at the end?) when the array is freed, just to have multiple times investing time to correct the pointers? Nah. As others said: This is a bad design. Use a linked list. -- You could insert an intermediate level by memory allocator if you want to call `free()` not that often. But it introduces a lot of potential for errors!

Comment: @thebusybee just to clarify, you're saying to do pretty well the same as I am now, but just not use malloc or realloc? Im finding it difficult then to know when to use these functions, if not in a situation like this

Comment: @TravelKidKurty: if you are storing list items inside a contiguous array, then simply store array indices instead of actual pointers. Or, is this block some sort of a pool of structs that you are using elsewhere?

Comment: How are `malloc()` or `realloc()` suppose to know what is a pointer and what is not? Each structure is user-defined, and so you need to write your correction code yourself. -- This is how development works: Define an algorithm, evaluate it, and repeat until all requirements are met.

Comment: Don't mix data in the block with pointers or meta information in the same block. It's making life unnecessarily difficult. But if you have data in a contiguous block it's just a case of doing pointer arithmetic to get the cell of data you need.

Comment: @Groo the function is to be used as a spell-checker. A dictionary text file is read in, and Im creating a trie from the words within the dictionary. A struct stores the letter with a link to the next letter of the word. These structs are shared because its a trie, so 1 struct can have a link to many other structs. After the dictionary trie is created, another text file is read in and compared to the members to determine if the text matches a word from the dictionary

Comment: *Im doing it this way so that all the structs in the list are stored in the same allocated block, so I can then free all data used by simply freeing just the 1 block.*  That comes at the cost of using `realloc()` a whole bunch of times. And `realloc()` is effectively the same as `malloc()` then `memcpy()` then `free()`.  So you're not saving anything over calling `malloc()` and `free()` for each node, and in fact you're causing a lot of extraneous copying.

Answer (score 0):

There's no in-built solution, because the general use case for `realloc()` is to increase the size of some opaque content while it's being used by its "owner."  The runtime doesn't know who has referenced it or what's hiding in some other chunk of dynamic memory, so all the references need to be updated manually.

Unfortunately, the way you describe your program's architecture in the comments, even the most traditional approach (build a hash table--or equivalent data structure--that maps "handles" or other fake pointers to real pointers) won't get you very far, because it sounds like you'd still need to search through memory and rebuild the entire table every time.

If you're married to allocating memory for all of the objects at once, your best bet is probably going to be to host your list inside of an array (or memory that you treat like an array), using the array indices instead of your pointers.

That said, since the worry you mention in the comments is deallocating a linked list, just bite the bullet and do that manually.  Deallocating is only marking the space available, so even thousands of elements aren't going to take much time and nobody is ever going to care if the program is a little bit slow on *exit*, even if you have billions of elements.

Answer (score 0):

At its most basic, if you only have one linked list of structures you only need to know the address of the first structure and the address of the structure that you're currently reading in order to navigate through all members of the list.

If you have more than one linked list, then you will need to store the same data, but for that list.

For example (unchecked pseudo code):

```
struct ListIndexEntry
{
  ListEntry* startOfLinkedList;
  ListEntry* currentLinkedListEntryBeingRead;
};

//fixed size data for structure, but could be variable if the structure has a size of data indicator.
stuct ListEntry
{
  ListEntry* previousEntry;
  ListEntry* nextEntry;
  char Data[255]; 
}

struct ListIndexEntry ListTable[20]; //fixed table for 20 linked lists
```

So you allocate memory for the first element of your first linked list and update the first entry in the `ListTable` accordingly.

*Okay - I see from comments that have appeared whilst I've been typing that you may already know this.*

You can speed up navigation of large linked lists by using multiple layers of linked lists. Thus you could allocate a large block of memory that would store multiple `ListEntry` e.g.

```
struct ListBlock
{
  void* previousBlock;
  void* nextBlock;
  ListEntry Entries[2000]; 
}
```

then you allocate memory for a `ListBlock` and store your `ListEntry`s contiguously within it.

The `ListIndexEntry` would now be:

```
struct ListIndexEntry
{
  ListBlock* startOfLinkedList;
  ListBlock* currentListBlock;
  ListEntry* currentLinkedListEntryBeingRead;
}
```

You can then coarsely allocate memory, navigate and deallocate memory by `ListBlock`.

You'll still need to handle the pointers within the table and the current `ListBlock` manually.

Admittedly this means that there may be some unused memory within the last `ListBlock` in the list and so you'll need to choose your `ListBlock.Entries` size carefully.

Answer (score 0):

From the description, I would describe this pattern as an object pool. The idea that you don't want to allocate lots of small structs, but instead store them in a single contiguous array means that you basically want an efficient `malloc`. However, the premise (or a "contract") behind the object pool is that the caller is "borrowing" items from the pool, and requires that the borrowed objects are not destroyed by the pool implementation before they are returned back to the pool.

So, you can do three things:

1. Make this array of structs coupled to the implementation, and store array indices instead of pointers. This means that the linked list code "knows" that it's using an array under the hood and the entire code is written to accomodate this. Accessing a list item is always done by indexing the array.
2. Write a memory pool which will grow as needed by adding blocks of structs into the pool, instead of resizing and moving existing blocks. This is a useful data structure and I've used it a lot, but it's most useful when you do rarely need to grow and do lots of borrowing and returning -- it's faster than malloc, doesn't suffer from fragmentation and likely exhibits better reference locality. But if you rarely need to return items to the pool, it's likely an overkill over a generic `malloc` implementation.
3. Obviusly, the third approach is to just use `malloc` and don't worry about this until you've profiled it and identified it to be an actual bottleneck.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a brief code example of an object pool by chance? By your description, I dont think it's what I would need for my circumstance, as I'm more just populating the trie, checking, then deleting. I am curious of your idea tho for future reference

Answer (score 0):

As commentors pointed out and confirmed, *"Don't mix embedded pointers and realloc(). It's a fundamentally bad design."*. I ended up changing the embedded pointers to instead hold an offset value, to direct a pointer to the appropriate node. Many others commented with great *list* suggestions, but as Im using a *trie* (I was late to state this, my fault), I found this to be an easier fix without completely re-doing all of the general basis of my code